# Encrypt in python and decrypt in Java with AES-CFB

Tags: java, python, encryption, pycrypto, cfb-mode

I am aware of a question very similar to this ([How do I encrypt in Python and decrypt in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440777/how-do-i-encrypt-in-python-and-decrypt-in-java)) but I have a different problem.

My problem is, I am not able to decrypt in Java correctly. Despite using the correct key and IV, I still get garbage characters after decryption. I don't have any compile/run-time errors or exceptions in Java so I believe I am using the right parameters for decryption.

Python Encryption Code -

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
key = '0123456789012345'
iv = 'RandomInitVector'
raw = 'samplePlainText'
cipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CFB,iv)
encrypted = base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))
```

Java Decryption Code -

```
private static String KEY = "0123456789012345";
public static String decrypt(String encrypted_encoded_string) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
    InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

      String plain_text = "";
      try{
          byte[] encrypted_decoded_bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted_encoded_string);
          String encrypted_decoded_string = new String(encrypted_decoded_bytes);
          String iv_string = encrypted_decoded_string.substring(0,16); //IV is retrieved correctly.

          IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(iv_string.getBytes());
          SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

          Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

          plain_text = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted_decoded_bytes));//Returns garbage characters
          return plain_text;

      }  catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
      }

      return plain_text;
 }
```

Is there anything obvious that I am missing?

Comment: @Pavneet Singh Could you please elaborate why?

Comment: oh i thought you found some compiled time error or something in code , letme take back my flag

Comment: @PavneetSingh No problem. I should have been clear. I just updated the question stating that I don't have any compile-time or run-time exceptions.

Comment: could you print java output with garbage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Cipher Feedback (CFB) mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_.28CFB.29) is a family of modes. It is parametrized by the segment size (or register size). PyCrypto has a default [segment size of 8 bit](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/v2.6.1/src/block_template.c#L182) and Java (actually OpenJDK) has a default segment size the [same as the block size](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/com/sun/crypto/provider/CipherCore.java#228) (128 bit for AES).

If you want CFB-128 in pycrypto, you can use `AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size=128)`. If you want CFB-8 in Java, you can use `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB8/NoPadding");`.

---

Now that we have that out the way, you have other problems:

- Always specify the character set you're using, because it can change between different JVMs: `new String(someBytes, "UTF-8")` and `someString.getBytes("UTF-8")`. When you do, be consistent.
- Never use a String to store binary data (`new String(encrypted_decoded_bytes);`). You can copy the bytes directly: `IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOf(encrypted_decoded_bytes, 16));` and `cipher.doFinal(Arrays.copyOfRange(encrypted_decoded_bytes, 16, encrypted_decoded_bytes.length))`.
- In Java, you're assuming that the IV is written in front of the ciphertext and then encoded together, but in Python, you're never doing anything with the IV. I guess you posted incomplete code.
- It is crucial for CFB mode to use a **different** IV every time if the key stays the same. If you don't change the IV for every encryption, you will create a multi-time pad which enables an attacker to deduce the plaintext even without knowing the key.

Comment: Using ''''AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size=128)'''' did the trick! And yes, I have posted incomplete code. I am appending IV in python too. Updated the code. Thanks for the other inputs too!

Comment: Thanks for this @Artjom B. It worked and I got the first 8 bytes correctly. The problem is that the returned buffer from the Cipher.doFinal is of size 8 instead of 16. Do you have any idea how to get an output buffer with a length of 16?

Comment: @OzShabat Sorry, I can't help you there. I also don't see why it would be 8 bytes. Perhaps something else is going on. Are you sure, you're using AES and not DES? Are you sure that the JRE that you use hasn't switched from CFB-128 to CFB-64?

Comment: @ArtjomB. you saved my a**.  This is so obscure.  Works great `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB8/NoPadding");`.  Needed this for Clojure.  Do you have a GitHub so I can sponsor you?  Thanks again!!

Comment: @snakes I'm glad I could help you out. I have a GitHub profile with the same name as here, but I haven't yet set up my sponsors account. I've checked some profiles of my heroes and they also didn't set it up yet. So I can't give another suggestion instead. ;) Buy somebody a beer when you're next time at a bar. :)

Comment: It's a deal! THANK YOU!