# Java AES Decryption with keyFile using BouncyCastle SSL

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I am trying to write a Java code decrypt a file encrypted with AES256 using BouncyCastle compatible with OpenSSL decryption.

**s_key is the file provided which contains the key that will be used to encrypt and decrypt**

Steps to be done: 1 - Read the key file 2 - Use the key provided to decrypt file inputfilename

Below I have use so far but I am getting error:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.MD5Digest;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.io.CipherOutputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;

import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;


public class test5_encrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {


        File file = new File("/home/roxane/key");
        String passwordStr = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");

        String outputPath = "/home/roxane/test1";
        String inputPath = "/home/roxane/test";


        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte salt[] = new byte[8];
        random.nextBytes(salt);

// Derive 32 bytes key (AES_256) and 16 bytes IV
        byte[] password = passwordStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator pbeGenerator = new OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator(new MD5Digest()); // SHA256 as of v1.1.0 (if in OpenSSL the default digest is applied)
        pbeGenerator.init(password, salt);
        ParametersWithIV parameters = (ParametersWithIV) pbeGenerator.generateDerivedParameters(256, 128);// keySize, ivSize in bits
        System.out.println(parameters.getIV());


// Decrypt with AES-256
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath)) {

           // Encrypt chunkwise (for large data)
            PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()));
            cipher.init(false, parameters);
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputPath);
                 CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher)) {
                int bytesRead = -1;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024 * 1024];
                while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    cos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }


    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.bouncycastle.crypto.io.InvalidCipherTextIOException: Error finalising cipher data
    at decrypt.test5_encrypt.main(test5_encrypt.java:61)
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.crypto.io.InvalidCipherTextIOException: Error finalising cipher data
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.io.CipherOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at decrypt.test5_encrypt.main(test5_encrypt.java:59)
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a password, OpenSSL stores the ciphertext in a specific format, namely the ASCII encoding of `Salted__`, followed by the 8 bytes salt, then the actual ciphertext.

During decryption, the salt must not be randomly generated (as it is done in the posted code), otherwise the wrong key and IV will be derived. Instead, the salt must be determined from the metadata of the ciphertext. Also the use of the stream classes must be fixed:

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.MD5Digest;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.io.CipherInputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV; 

...

String inputPath = "...";   // path to enc file
String outputPath = "...";  // path to dec file
String passwordStr = "...";

// Decrypt with AES-256, CBC using streams
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputPath)){

    // Determine salt from OpenSSL format
    fis.readNBytes(8); // Skip prefix Salted__
    byte[] salt = fis.readNBytes(8); // Read salt
    
    // Derive 32 bytes key (AES_256) and 16 bytes IV via EVP_BytesToKey()
    byte[] password = passwordStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator pbeGenerator = new OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator(new MD5Digest()); // SHA256 as of v1.1.0 (if in OpenSSL the default digest is applied)
    pbeGenerator.init(password, salt);
    ParametersWithIV parameters = (ParametersWithIV) pbeGenerator.generateDerivedParameters(256, 128); // keySize, ivSize in bits
    
    // Decrypt chunkwise (for large data)
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()));
    cipher.init(false, parameters);
    try (CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath)) {
        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024 * 1024]; // chunksize, e.g. 64 MiB
        while ((bytesRead = cis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }               
    }
}
```

This is functionally equivalent to the OpenSSL statement:

```
openssl enc -d -aes256 -k <passpharse> -in <enc file> -out <dec file>
```

Note that OpenSSL applied MD5 as digest by default in earlier versions and SHA256 as of v.1.1.0. Code and OpenSSL statement must use the same digest for compatibility.
In the code the digest is explicitly specified, in the OpenSSL statement it can be explicitly set via the *-md* option so that matching is possible on both sides.
Keep in mind that `EVP_BytesToKey()`, which is used by default by OpenSSL for key derivation, is deemed insecure nowadays.

---

Addition regarding Java 8: For Java 8, e.g. the following implementation can be applied for the determination of the salt:

```java
int i = 0;
byte[] firstBlock = new byte[16]; 
while (i < firstBlock.length) {
    i += fis.read(firstBlock, i, firstBlock.length - i);
}
byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(firstBlock, 8, 16);
```

The loop is necessary because [`read(byte[],int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-), unlike `readNBytes(int)`, does *not guarantee* that the buffer is *completely filled* (considering here the non-EOF and non-error case).

If you omit the loop (which means using the equivalent [`read(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read-byte:A-)), the code will still run for those JVMs which also fill the buffer completely. Since this applies to the most common JVMs for small buffer sizes the code will mostly work, see the comment by dave_thompson_085. However, this is not guaranteed for *any* JVM and is therefore less robust (though probably not by much).

Comment: I am using Java8 readNBytes is available for inputstream?

Comment: @RoxaneFelton: per the documentation [`InputStream.readNBytes(int)` "since 11"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readNBytes(int)) and 8 is before/below 11. Although the general contract of `InputStream.read` doesn't ensure 'full' read (to limit or EOF/error), for file input and a small buffer like this it actually will do so, and I would just use that.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes, the return type is different read will return int whereas readNbytes will return a byte array

Comment: @Topaco Just to help understand if its AES 128 what are the changes to key, IV and Salt compared to AES 256 as I believe the same code can be utilized for AES 128

Comment: @RoxaneFelton - Changing the key size has no effect on salt and IV. In the OpenSSL statement *-aes128* must be used (instead of *-aes256*) and in the `generateDerivedParameters()` call `128` must be passed as key size in bits (= first parameter) (instead of `256`). That's all.

Comment: @Topaco: From ParametersWithIV parameters how can we get the Secret Key Spec

Comment: @RoxaneFelton - The key in binary fromat can be derived from the parameters of `ParametersWithIV` and from this `SecretKeySpec` can be created. For more details please ask a new question. Thx.

Comment: @Topaco sure. Below is the link to the question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998457/get-key-and-iv-values-using-bouncy-castle

Comment: @Topaco I need to encrypt the key file using RSA aswell. I have tried but it didnt work out. I have posted the question in the link here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73007096/rsa-oaep-encryption-and-decryption-of-symmetric-key-file