# RSA -OAEP encryption and decryption of Symmetric Key file

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a symmetric key file (256 and 128) using RSAES - OAEP but I am getting error while encrypting :

File Sizes to encrypt: 256 and 128

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;


 public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

                KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                kpg.initialize(2048);
                KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
                String inputPath = "/home/roxane/Music/test_09";
                String inFile = "/home/roxane/Downloads/s_key";
                String encfile = "/home/roxane/Music/s_key.enc";

                // get key pair
                PublicKey pub = kp.getPublic();
                PrivateKey PrivateKey = kp.getPrivate();

                // Write Key Pair
                try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(inputPath + ".key")) {
                    out.write(kp.getPrivate().getEncoded());
                }

                try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(inputPath + ".pub")) {
                    out.write(kp.getPublic().getEncoded());
                }

                //restore kEys
                byte[] pubbytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputPath + ".pub"));
                X509EncodedKeySpec ks = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubbytes);
                KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                PublicKey pub1 = kf.generatePublic(ks);


                byte[] privbytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputPath + ".key"));
                PKCS8EncodedKeySpec ks1 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privbytes);
                KeyFactory kf1 = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                PrivateKey pvt = kf1.generatePrivate(ks1);


                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-512ANDMGF1PADDING");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pvt);
                try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inFile);
                     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(encfile)) {
                    processFile(cipher, in, out);
                }
                
                
                
            }

            static private void processFile(Cipher ci,InputStream in,OutputStream out)
                    throws javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException,
                    javax.crypto.BadPaddingException,
                    java.io.IOException
            {
                byte[] ibuf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(ibuf)) != -1) {
                    byte[] obuf = ci.update(ibuf, 0, len);
                    if ( obuf != null ) out.write(obuf);
                }
                byte[] obuf = ci.doFinal();
                if ( obuf != null ) out.write(obuf);
            }
```

Error: Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: OAEP cannot be used to sign or verify signatures

Requesting help in the code encrytption and decryption of the files compatible with openssl. I am open to use bouncycastle if required

Comment: RSA encryption is performed with the public key of the recipient. You're trying to use a private key.

Comment: ... but for a period last century it was thought clever to misdescribe RSA signing and verifying as 'encrypting with the private key and decrypting with the public key' (i.e. backwards) and unfortunately this mistake was embedded in the Java cryptoprovider for 'classic' RSA (in Java terms, PKCS1Padding) only -- thus the error message because it treats your mistaken call as an attempt to sign. (@PresidentJamesK.Polk)

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  I have updated the key rightly pointed out . I am now getting an error :
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 126 bytes

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 i have updated the key but now i am getting a different error

Comment: RSA can only encrypt a limited amount of data, how much depends on the key size and padding. [Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100) you can find an overview of the maximum data sizes for OAEP, which is 126 bytes for your parameters (2048 bits key, OAEP with SHA512 digest). The question that arises is why your symmetric key is larger. The key sizes for AES (assuming it's AES) are 16 (AES-128), 24 (AES-192) and 32 bytes (AES-256), so all should be no problem. Did you mix up bits and bytes and try to store 128/192/256 bytes instead of 16/24/32 bytes?

Comment: @Topaco I think yes. The file which I used earliar for AES 256 encryption is 256 bytes

Comment: @Topaco Its the Password file for AES 256 which contains the key and IV