# Decrypt file in java that was encrypted with openssl

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, jca

The file is encrypted using the following command:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in file.txt -out file_enc.txt -k 1234567812345678
```

The file is decrypted using the following command:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in file_enc.txt -out file.txt -k 1234567812345678
```

After printing the salt and key in java I get:

Key=b796fbb416732ce13d39dbb60c0fb234a8f6d70e49df1c7e62e55e81d33a6bff774254ac99268856bf3afe0b95defdad

and in cmd I get :

salt=2D7C7E1C84BD6693
key=B796FBB416732CE13D39DBB60C0FB234A8F6D70E49DF1C7E62E55E81D33A6BFF

iv =774254AC99268856BF3AFE0B95DEFDAD

after running :

openssl enc  -aes-256-cbc   -in file.txt  -out file_enc.txt -pbkdf2 -k 1234567812345678 -p

I am using the following code but the encrypted file is printing  :

```java
public static void main(String args[]) throws InvalidKeySpecException,
                                              NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                                              IllegalBlockSizeException,
                                              InvalidKeyException,
                                              BadPaddingException,
                                              InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
                                              NoSuchPaddingException,
                                              IOException {
    String password = "1234567812345678";
    String algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = AESUtil.generateIv();
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("file_enc.txt");
    File inputFile = resource.getFile();
    byte[] salt = new byte[8], data = new byte[1024], tmp; 
        int keylen = 32, ivlen = 16, cnt;
        try( InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile) ){
            if( is.read(salt) != 8 || !Arrays.equals(salt, "Salted__".getBytes() )
                    || is.read(salt) != 8 ) throw new Exception("salt fail");
            byte[] keyandIV = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2withHmacSHA256") 
                    .generateSecret( new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 10000, (keylen+ivlen)*8) 
                    ).getEncoded();
            System.out.println("Key "+ byteArrayToHex(keyandIV));
            Cipher ciph = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 
            ciph.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyandIV,0,keylen,"AES"), 
                    new IvParameterSpec(keyandIV,keylen,ivlen));
            while( (cnt = is.read(data)) > 0 ){
                if( (tmp = ciph.update(data, 0, cnt)) != null ) System.out.write(tmp);
            }
            tmp = ciph.doFinal(); System.out.write(tmp);
        }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Where in your `openssl` command did you specify (a) a random IV? and (b) `PKCS5Padding`? and are you aware of `CipherInputStream`?

Comment: You can't be expecting to decrypt the file encrypted by openssl can you? If you encrypt it yourself using your own elements, you shouldn't have a problem

Comment: In command i didn't  specify neither random IV nor  PKCS5Padding

Comment: So, err, why are you doing both in the Java code?

Comment: @g00se You are mistaken. OpenSSL is interoperable with Java encryption. Otherwise nothing would work.

Comment: The file will be encrypted with the method above in cmd and then it will be sent to the application to be read

Comment: But why are you doing the things I mentioned in the Java code when you aren't doing them at the OpenSSL end? Surely you can identify this as a problem by now?

Comment: I was able to solve it and my code worked

Answer (score 5):

Your `getKeyFromPassword` creates a `SecretkeyFactory` for PBKDF2 (with HmacSHA256) but doesn't use it; instead you use the password as the key, which is wrong -- unless you actually wanted to do openssl enc with a key (`-K` uppercase and hex which should be 64 hexits/32 bytes for AES-256) and not a password (`-k` lowercase and any characters or any length). (Below IIRC 18, `String.getBytes()` gives you a JVM-dependent encoding which for an arbitrary string like a real password can vary on different systems or environments, which will cause cryptography using it to fail, but for the example string you show all realistic encodings give the same result.)

But even if you did use this factory it wouldn't be correct because `openssl enc` by default does not use PBKDF2, it uses a function called `EVP_BytesToKey` which is based on but different from PBKDF1. In OpenSSL 1.1.1 up, you can *optionally* specify `-pbkdf2` (and/or `-iter N`) in `enc`, and if you don't it gives a warning message about 'deprecated key derivation' which you should have noticed, so I assume you're either using obsolete OpenSSL or trying to prevent us accurately understanding your situation and thus making it unlikely to get a useful answer.

Also, with *either* kind of key derivation (old `EVP_BytesToKey` or optional new PBKDF2) `openssl enc` by default uses salt, which is randomly generated and written in the file when encrypting; when decrypting you must read the salt from the file and use it. Specifically, skip or discard the first 8 bytes (which are the fixed characters `Salted__`) and take the next 8 bytes as salt, then the remainder of the file as ciphertext

Depending on what you want (or maybe your users/customers/etc want) to do there are three possibilities:

1. encrypt with `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k ...` with the default derivation (as now) and code the Java to read the salt from the file as above, implement `EVP_BytesToKey` using the password and that salt, and use its output for both the key and IV in the Java `Cipher` (for aes-256-cbc generate 48 bytes and use the first 32 bytes as key and the last 16 bytes as IV). `EVP_BytesToKey` uses a hash which defaults to SHA256 for OpenSSL 1.1.0 up and MD5 for lower versions, so you need to know which version did the encryption for this to work, or else you can *specify* the hash on the `enc` command with `-md $hash`. There have been hundreds of Qs about this going back over a decade; search for `EVP_BytesToKey` to find some of them.
2. encrypt with `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -k ...` and code the Java to read the salt from the file as above and *use* the keyfactory you created to generate 48 bytes of 'key' material, which you must actually split into key and IV as above in the Java `Cipher`.
3. encrypt with `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -K 64hexits -iv 32hexits` and code the Java to use the corresponding binary key and IV values.

> In command i didn't specify neither random IV nor PKCS5Padding

When you use either old or new key derivation in `openssl enc` it *derives* the IV rather than specifying it separately; only if you use explicit key (`-K` uppercase) do you also specify `-iv`. `openssl enc` always defaults to the padding variously called pkcs5, pkcs7, or pkcs5/7, except when no padding is needed (stream ciphers like RC4 or ChaCha or stream modes like CTR, OFB, CFB).

---

Okay, you seem to be reading only about half of what I said. Most fundamentally, you still have `openssl enc` without `-pbkdf2` but are trying to decrypt in Java with PBKDF2, which is flat wrong. In addition you are reading the salt but then converting it to hex, which is wrong, the salt from the file is the correct salt, and you are generating a completely bogus random IV, not deriving it as I said.

To be concrete, if you (or I) encrypt a file **with -pbkdf2** like

```
 openssl enc -aes-cbc-256 -pbkdf2 -k 1234567812345678
```

which will only work on OpenSSL 1.1.1 up (since 2018), the following (minimalistic) Java code correctly decrypts it:

```
static void SO73456313OpensslEnc2_Java (String[] args) throws Exception {
    // file pw: decrypt openssl(1.1.1+) enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -k $pw
    byte[] salt = new byte[8], data = new byte[1024], tmp; 
    int keylen = 32, ivlen = 16, cnt;
    try( InputStream is = new FileInputStream(args[0]) ){
        if( is.read(salt) != 8 || !Arrays.equals(salt, "Salted__".getBytes() )
                || is.read(salt) != 8 ) throw new Exception("salt fail");
        byte[] keyandIV = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2withHmacSHA256") 
                .generateSecret( new PBEKeySpec(args[1].toCharArray(), salt, 10000, (keylen+ivlen)*8) 
                ).getEncoded();
        Cipher ciph = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 
        ciph.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyandIV,0,keylen,"AES"), 
                new IvParameterSpec(keyandIV,keylen,ivlen));
        while( (cnt = is.read(data)) > 0 ){
            if( (tmp = ciph.update(data, 0, cnt)) != null ) System.out.write(tmp);
        }
        tmp = ciph.doFinal(); System.out.write(tmp);
    }
}
```

Note in PBEKeySpec I used itercount=10000 which is the `enc` default. You can use a higher number like 65536, which may be desirable for security (but that part is offtopic here), if you specify it when encrypting like:

```
 openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 65536 -k ...
```

OTOH if you use the command you posted, which you must on OpenSSL 1.1.0 or lower, then you cannot decrypt using PBKDF2 at all.
For that case instead see
[How to decrypt file in Java encrypted with openssl command using AES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783062/how-to-decrypt-file-in-java-encrypted-with-openssl-command-using-aes)
[How to decode a string encoded with openssl aes-128-cbc using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947256/how-to-decode-a-string-encoded-with-openssl-aes-128-cbc-using-java)
[Java equivalent of an OpenSSL AES CBC encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508961/java-equivalent-of-an-openssl-aes-cbc-encryption)
[Java AES Decryption with keyFile using BouncyCastle SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72944988/java-aes-decryption-with-keyfile-using-bouncycastle-ssl)
[Looking for Java implementation for decrypting a message encrypted using openssl -aes-256-cbc -a -salt command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175864/looking-for-java-implementation-for-decrypting-a-message-encrypted-using-openssl)
and [CryptoJS AES encryption and Java AES decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432896/cryptojs-aes-encryption-and-java-aes-decryption) (cryptojs is sometimes compatible with OpenSSL, including the case in that Q).
For background see my detailed explanation at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption/#35614 or the bear's at
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/openssl-recover-key-and-iv-by-passphrase .

And remember, as noted in at least some of those earlier Qs, the command you posted uses EVP_BytesToKey with SHA256 in 1.1.0 up but MD5 in 1.0.2 and lower, so you need to know which OpenSSL was or will be used.

Comment: I changed the code and read the code but it is giving me : Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption. Also I am getting 'deprecated key derivation'  only on windows 7

Comment: Wow Dave this is an excellent answer with great detail, thanks for the time and effort!

Comment: @MIX2000: the Windows version doesn't matter (although if you're encrypting data because it's important or sensitive I hope you know Windows 7 is well past EOL and no longer secure); as I said it's the version of OpenSSL. If something else isn't giving the warning, it is using older OpenSSL. Do `openssl version` to see. And see my edit.