# Convert node js crypto.createDecypher in java

Tags: node.js, security, openssl, aes, cryptojs

am using crypto.createDecypher() to decrypt some encrypted text .I want to perform same kind of decryption in java also.But crypto.createDecypher takes pawword and encrypted text amd it internally generates key.There is no way to get that key as they have not made it public.How to do that decryption than in java as not having access to key.Using aes-256-ecb.Please suggest

Comment: There is no 'createDecypher'. If you meant 'createDecipher', the [extremely public documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatedecipheralgorithm-password-options) tells you how the (poor-quality) key derivation works. Also nodejs createCipher/createDecipher is actually the same as older commandline `openssl enc` with no salt, so see [my description and links to numerous Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73456313/decrypt-file-in-java-that-was-encrypted-with-openssl#73458599) on that.